# CROSS APPLY with encrypted column converted to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to put this Decompress CLR function to work with CROSS APPLY but so far I had not success. The Decompress functions works fine. The problem is to Decompress the column and call .nodes function as shown below. Please, if anyone could help me with that would be great.

```
SELECT
T0.Chassis.value('Model', 'varchar(50)')
FROM ANYTABLE c 
CROSS APPLY CAST( dbo.Decompress( CAST(content AS nvarchar(max)) ) AS xml).nodes('this part is correct') AS T0(Chassis)
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to split your cast to XML and the .nodes part.

```
SELECT T0.Chassis.value('Model', 'varchar(50)')
FROM ANYTABLE c 
  CROSS APPLY (select CAST( dbo.Decompress( CAST(content AS nvarchar(max)) ) AS xml)) as T(X)
  CROSS APPLY T.X.nodes('this part is correct') AS T0(Chassis)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mikael but I´ve found the answer:

According to the microsoft documentation:

The nodes() function cannot be applied directly to the results of a user-defined function. To use the nodes() function with the result of a scalar user-defined function, you can either assign the result of the user-defined function to a variable or use a derived table to assign a column alias to the user-defined function return value and then use CROSS APPLY to select from the alias.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282(v=SQL.90).aspx